# How to remove items from position i in std::set?

Tags: c++, stdset

```
std::set<int> tmp_{30, 40};
int i=0;
while(tmp_[i]==40)
{
    i++;
}

tmp_erase(i);
```

How do I remove an element at position i?I cannot use erase because `i` is not `std::set::iteretor`

Comment: Sets don't work this way.

Comment: The whole point of using an unordered set is, that for those there is no such thing as a "*position `i`*".

Comment: I suggest you to remove/fix the code, std::set has no operator [], nor it's needed for what you are asking, and it gives wrong hints about the question

Answer (score 2):

`[]` operator is not defined for `std::set`, thus you cannot erase element at a specified position. You can use `std::find` to find a specified element **by value**

```cpp
std::set<int> tmp_{30, 40};
auto i = std::find(tmp_.begin(), tmp_.end(), 40);
tmp_.erase(i);
```

*`erase` also have an overload for `const key_type& key`, so you can simply use `erase(40)`*

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49f16cfab9d866ff)

Comment: He wants to remove an item at a certain POSITION, not with a certain VALUE, anyway if you want to remove the item with value 40 you can simply use tmp_.erase(40) ....

Comment: @gabry yes, it reflects only to the provided code (which tries to find `40`). You solved it for position anyway! Although i see no reason why one would use positions in a set

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) to move an iterator to the position you want and then [std::set::erase()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) on that iterator to remove the item it points to and rebalance the tree:

```
std::set<int> tmp_{30, 40, 35, 50};

// remove the second element, 35, since set is ordered 
auto it = tmp_.begin();
std::advance(it, 1); // to remove 40, advance 2, to remove 50... 3
tmp_.erase(it);
```

... it's quite common to do this kind of operations on associative containers, mostly when they are linked to widgets or other external, linear objects, but you may also want to consider the use of [std::unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/) if the automatic reordering is not a desired behaviour or [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/).

Answer (score 0):

std::set is an Associative Containers and they are internally implemented by balanced binary trees.

**[]** operator is not applicable for sets.

You have to search for the element in the std::set using iterators or use find() function to find element in set and then erase it.